# iOS iPad storyboard is not being selected

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

It seems that Xcode 5 is not choosing to use my iPad storyboard for the iPad device even though i specified it.

This is how i told Xcode 5 to use iPad storyboard:

- I went to project settings under `General`
- Selected Devices: `Universal`
- Then i clicked on `iPad`
- And wrote `MainStoryboard-iPad.storyboard` in `Main Interface`

But for some reason even though i make changes to my `MainStoryboard-iPad` storyboard its not being showed when i try to run it on an iPad.

I only have two storyboards in my project

> MainStoryboard-iPad.storyboard

and

> MainStoryboard.storyboard

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Oh by the way, when i selected Universal the first time i got a box asking me something about copying (i never read it that carefully). I just hit Yes. Not sure what that box actually did.

**EDIT**

Code that runs in my AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        AppDelegate *app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainStoryBoard"];

        UINavigationController *nvc = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
        app.window.rootViewController = ivc;
}
```

Comment: Are you making any changes to how the UI is displayed in the AppDelegate? Like changing the root view controller?

Comment: Ahhh... yes i am! But not on the first screen

Comment: Can you post your code for that? It might be related.

Comment: Updated the question with the code

Comment: Same issue here.  In Xcode 5.0.2 in an app that was "universal" but only had an iPhone storyboard, I added a new storyboard and selected iPad.  In the General Target Settings, I can not select this storyboard for the iPad - Xcode keeps reverting it to the iPhone storyboard.  This is maddening.  No error message is output to the console.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered this a while ago.

These are the steps you need to do:

1. make sure the "Deployment Info" -> Devices is "Universal"
2. Create a storyboard for iPad (e.g) MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard
3. now go to your Infor.plist
4. add row for "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" and use MainStoryboard_iPad as the value of the string

Now you are good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overriding the default storyboard for the device type. You are grabbing MainStoryboard, instantiating a view controller from it and setting it as the root. This is normally handled by the storyboard itself. It uses the view controller that you have picked as the root. Try removing all of that code to manually set the storyboard.

Check this project on github for an example of storyboard switching without code: https://github.com/danielmackenzie/StoryboardSelection

Xcode project points to each storyboard per device type and the appropriate board is automatically chosen on launch.

Comment: It is perfectly acceptable to do what they are doing in their code. I do something simpler, the concern they should be looking at is why they are doing it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

Comment: Sure, this will work and should be in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. However, it's better to let the project/storyboard configuration handle the loading, especially if the only need for different storyboards is because of a different device type.

Comment: Except for having it in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` this doesn't matter. If you select `@"mainStoryboard"` in the code it will still do it's job and select the correct device it is running on. As this works perfectly fine for me when I have done this. So I would suggest your answer needs backing up with evidence.

Comment: I added an example project that automatically handles storyboard selection.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an entry for the iPad in your app's info.plist

Look in your Supporting Files group for the info.plist for your app.

You'll see an entry for the iPhone's storyboard, but not one for the iPad.

The iPhone entry should look like this:

```
Main storyboard file base name
```

and it should have the name of your iPhone's storyboard (sans file extension) as the string value for it.  Something like this:

```
iPhone-Storyboard
```

Add a new entry into the pList and enter this string as the key:

```
Main storyboard file base name (iPad)
```

Make sure the data type is string.

You can now select the iPad storyboard that you want from the app's General Settings on your Target.

I JUST ran into this as well and thought you'd like a clear explanation and solution.

Sometimes, Xcode is rather maddening, isn't it?  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

// Override point for customization after application launch.

```
if (<your implementation>) {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" 
                                                             bundle: nil];
    YourViewController *yourController = (YourViewController *)[mainStoryboard     
      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourViewControllerID"];
    self.window.rootViewController = yourController;
}
```

return YES;

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is not taking into account your device. AFAIK, there is no method that looks at your naming postfix ("-iPad") and automatically selects the right storyboard file.

To fix it, simply replace the call to instantiate your storyboard with some logic to pick the right one based on device.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard;

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard-iPad" bundle:nil];
} else 
{
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
}
```

Comment: Storyboards and the Xcode project are designed to choose the appropriate storyboard file automatically. This code should not be needed at all.