# XCode does not recognize iPad storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have two storyboards Main and Main_iPad.  My problem is that, in both of iphone and ipad devices, only Main storyboard gets selected and executed. What I did is:

[image: iPad storyboard selection]
iPad storyboard selection
[image: iphone storyboard selection]
iphone storyboard selection
[image: I dont know its usage]
I dont know its usage

So, whenever I change Universal from Main to Main_iPAd my it is working on iPad but crashes on iphone. But when I change it to Main, then it works both on iPad and iphone but, does not recognize the model inside Main_iPad. What can be problem?

Comment: Check out [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094551/ios-ipad-storyboard-is-not-being-selected?rq=1) and see if any of their solutions work for you.

Comment: Main is choosen anyway. Don't select anything for Universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this same problem. My conclusion is that you can't configure this correctly by editing the target (as you are doing). You have to go directly into the *Info.plist* file and set it up there, by editing the "Main storyboard file base name" and "Main storyboard file base name (iPad)" entries.